# Dúvida em alocação de memória dinâmica

Tags: c++, alocação

No código abaixo, liberar memória de B libera também de A?

```
int* A = new int[4]; 
int *B = A; 
delete[] B;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, pois ambos os ponteiros apontam para a mesma região de memória..

Tenha em mente que o ponteiro apenas indica onde seus dados estão, apagar B não apaga A, apaga o conteúdo também apontado por A.

Após a alocação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Após a liberação da memória:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe também que A continua apontado para a região de memória, enquanto B após o delete aponta para uma região explicitamente inválida.

Comment: `"Observe também que A continua apontado para a região de memória, enquanto B após o delete aponta para uma região explicitamente inválida."` ??? A e B continuam iguais a apontando para a mesma região de memória, uma potencialmente inválida.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento pessoal.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal testei no Visual Studio e sugiro que faça isso também... a construção assembly gera a instrução `mov dword ptr[B], 8123h` que modifica o ponteiro B após a limpeza da memória `call operator delete (0124108Ch)`

Comment: @LeonardoBosquett Errado. O que acontece é que se, após deletar a memória, você tentar ler denovo pelo mesmo ponteiro, pode obter uma leitura válida de um valor desconhecido por que a memória foi reutilizada. O que o visual studio faz, **exclusivamente no modo de debug**, é setar o ponteiro para um valor que indubitavelmente causará o crash (`0x00008123`). Assim você é avisado se fizer algo errado, em vez de ter um programa que aparentemente funciona. No entanto ele não nota a relação entre o B e o A e só seta o B. Isso é um extra do VS, não um comportamento correto do C++. Não se limite ao VS